# Email address variable causing items to disappear from email template

Tags: email, template

I've inserted a variable to bring in the customer email into the default new order template however when I added this I noticed that the items and total amount now disappear - any idea what's going on?

I addeded: ({{var order.shipping_address.format('html')}} Email: {{var order.getCustomerEmail()}})

and this seems to disappear  {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}}
{{var payment_html|raw}}

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<table>
    <tr class="email-intro">
        <td>
            <p class="greeting">{{trans "%customer_name," customer_name=$order_data.customer_name}} ({{var order.shipping_address.format('html')}} Email: {{var order.getCustomerEmail()}}) </p>
            <p>
                {{trans "Thank you for your order from %store_name." store_name=$store.frontend_name}}
                {{trans "Once your package ships we will send you a tracking number."}}
                {{trans 'You can check the status of your order by <a href="%account_url">logging into your account</a>.' account_url=$this.getUrl($store,'customer/account/',[_nosid:1]) |raw}}
            </p>
            <p>
                {{trans 'If you have questions about your order, you can email us at <a href="mailto:%store_email">%store_email</a>' store_email=$store_email |raw}}{{depend store_phone}} {{trans 'or call us at <a href="tel:%store_phone">%store_phone</a>' store_phone=$store_phone |raw}}{{/depend}}.
                {{depend store_hours}}
                    {{trans 'Our hours are <span class="no-link">%store_hours</span>.' store_hours=$store_hours |raw}}
                {{/depend}}
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-summary">
        <td>
            <h1>{{trans 'Your Order <span class="no-link">#%increment_id</span>' increment_id=$order.increment_id |raw}}</h1>
            <p>{{trans 'Placed on <span class="no-link">%created_at</span>' created_at=$created_at_formatted |raw}}</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-information">
        <td>
            {{depend order_data.email_customer_note}}
            <table class="message-info">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{var order_data.email_customer_note|escape|nl2br}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{/depend}}
            <table class="order-details">
                <tr>
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3>{{trans "Billing Info"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var formattedBillingAddress|raw}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{depend order_data.is_not_virtual}}
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3>{{trans "Shipping Info"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var formattedShippingAddress|raw}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h3>{{trans "Payment Method"}}</h3>
                        {{var payment_html|raw}}
                    </td>
                    {{depend order_data.is_not_virtual}}
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h3>{{trans "Shipping Method"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var order.shipping_description}}</p>
                        {{if shipping_msg}}
                        <p>{{var shipping_msg}}</p>
                        {{/if}}
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}}
{{var payment_html|raw}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think custom variable is causing the issue. If you are creating this template in backend then please try below solution,

set in db table: "email_template" column **is_legacy = 1** for this new order email template.

Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61200220/12110977) for more details.

Comment: It would be useful when answering a question to explain why the solution is required and what effect the changes you are proposing have. What is the *is_legacy* setting, what does it do when set to *1* ?

Comment: @paj I have updated my answer. Thanks!